# LoginAsync() Hangs Indefinately When no Connection is Made

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-sdk

Calling await auth.LoginAsync() to connect to Windows Live (I am connecting to OneDrive) on Windows Phone 8.1 will hang indefinitely if a connection cannot be made).  I have tried several approaches at wrapping this call into a task that will timeout, with no success.

This is a follow on from my post in the Live Connect Forum (now apparently archived), at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/930f1e9b-75a3-4c61-b269-b7e78aa55bce/loginasync-hangs-indefinately-when-not-connected-to-the-internet?forum=messengerconnect.

It was suggested that this was going to be fixed in a new release, however I do not know if this is the case.  Is anybody able to tell me if this has been resolved?

Note that I have changed the question a little since my initial post.  I am now checking to ensure that I have a connection to the internet. as suggested in the same post in the Windows Phone 8 forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/onedrive/en-US/8e23edb5-45ec-40de-88e8-229b24cde8f2/loginasync-hangs-when-attempting-to-log-into-skydrive-with-no-internet-connection?forum=wpdevelop).  This makes the problem less common, but the call can still hang when connected to the internet, for example when there the connection is poor, or when the call simply fails for no apparent reason.

Comment: LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient("<XXXXXX>");
     LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access" });

Comment: How do you know a connection has not been made? I'm seeing LoginAsync sometimes timeout and don't know why - there appears to be nothing in the logs as to what the issue is. Sometimes it works fine and other times my task times out.